# How to bind with XML data using master-detail in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, binding

I have an XML file with these nodes:

```
<Product>
   <Name>...
   <Color>...
   <Price>...
</Product>
```

I have a listbox that displays all the Name's in the XML file like this:

```
 <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel >
                    <TextBlock Text = "{Binding Name}" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

When an item in the listbox is selected, I want to display the selected product's Color and Price on 2 label controls.

How do I bind the Color and Price to the selected Name? 
This means I need to get the Color and Price info from the XML file because the listbox has only the Name.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks - I found this question and the answer below very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SelectedItem` will be the whole item, with all three elements, so something like this should do:

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBox1}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Color}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=Price}" />
</StackPanel>
```

*(Could use `Binding.StringFormat` to prepend a label, also the [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) control itself is for labelling things, **not** displaying text)*

Comment: Thanks - been looking around and this was exactly what I needed.